# Remove element img with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this HTML:

```
<li>
    <input type="radio" class="checkbox" name="myName" id="Id001"/>
    One
    <img class="resetRadio" src="star.png"/>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="radio" class="checkbox" name="myName" id="Id002"/>
    Two
    <img class="resetRadio" src="star.png"/>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="radio" class="checkbox" name="myName" id="Id003"/>
    Three
    <img class="resetRadio" src="star.png"/>
</li>
```

And I want to remove the `img` of all `li` elements except the first one.
In the HTML document there are a lot of other `li`, `input`, and `img` elements.

The only thing I have is the name of the input (`myName`).

I tried:

```
var radios = $(':radio[name="myName"]');
radios.parent().remove(".resetRadio");
```

To remove all `img`but it doesn't work (first I want to remove all, then all except the first)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code would remove parents of radiobuttons with class `resetRadio`- whitch you don't have. You want to remove children of said parents - with the class `resetRadio`.
refine your second line to reflect this logic:

```
radios.parent().find(".resetRadio").remove();
```

to remove all but first change first line to:

```
var radios = $(':radio[name="myName"]:gt(0)');
```

Comment: thank you. it's nice with jquery I get an answer quickly on stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 3):

To remove the image from every list item greater than index 0, you could do the following:

```
$("li:gt(0) img.resetRadio").remove();
```

If you only wanted to remove the images that are siblings of the radio buttons, you could check the siblings and remove from that:

```
$(":radio[name=myName]").nextAll("img.resetRadio").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

This will remove all the images that are direct descendant of `li` elements, except for the first `li` element.

```
$('li:not(:first-child) > img').remove()
```

Note that it uses a valid CSS selector, so you may want do **hide** the images using CSS with

```
li:not(:first-child) > img {
    display: none;
}
```

so you won't rely only on JS.